# Excel VBA: Create new row below and copy only cells with formulae

Tags: format

I am using this code from a command button to add a row below the active row, but I need it to either copy ONLY the cells with formulae in Column E, G and H, or better yet, clear the contents of Columns A-D, and F (Column B will copy down a dropdown box and I need that to remain). I need it to keep all formatting such as borders, etc.

```
'''
Sub NewRow()
Dim R As Long
    Dim C As Long
    R = Selection.Row
    With Rows(R)
        .Copy
        .Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Cells(R + 1, 1).Select
End Sub
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).ClearContents 'column A
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).ClearContents 'column B
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).ClearContents 'column C
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 4).ClearContents 'column D
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 6).ClearContents 'column F
```

Works just fine.